# Analysing Multiple Choice Values in R - Getting Frequency count of Variables

Tags: r, dplyr, frequency, data-analysis

I imported the following data in which one of the questions was structured like this:

Question a) Type_of_input [MULTIPLE SELECT]

1. 1:Fertiliser
2. 2:Pesticide
3. 3:Herbicide
4. 4:Sprayer

Question b) Total Volume.

In the data.frame, the data is split in a matrix with each of the options being in separate columns and the observations being 0 and 1. 1 is if the option was selected and 0 if the option wasn't. see below a mock up of the `data.frame`.

```
Type_of_input <- c("1:Fertiliser|2:Pesticide|4:Sprayer", "2:Pesticide|3:Herbicides", "2:Pesticide|3:Herbicide|4:Sprayer")
Fertiliser <- c(1,0,0)
Pesticide <- c(1,1,1)
Herbicide <- c(0,1,1)
Sprayer <- c(1,0,1)
total_volume <- c(40,50,60)
df_inputs <- data.frame(Type_of_input, Fertiliser, Pesticide, Herbicide, Sprayer, volume)

df_inputs

                       Type_of_input Fertiliser Pesticide Herbicide Sprayer total_volume
1 1:Fertiliser|2:Pesticide|4:Sprayer          1         1         0       1           40
2           2:Pesticide|3:Herbicides          0         1         1       0           50
3  2:Pesticide|3:Herbicide|4:Sprayer          0         1         1       1           60
```

How do I get a frequency table count of each of the inputs and their `total_volume`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one solution, where you calculate the sum for each column of interest

```
Type_of_input <- c("1:Fertiliser|2:Pesticide|4:Sprayer", "2:Pesticide|3:Herbicides", "2:Pesticide|3:Herbicide|4:Sprayer")
Fertiliser <- c(1,0,0)
Pesticide <- c(1,1,1)
Herbicide <- c(0,1,1)
Sprayer <- c(1,0,1)
df_inputs <- data.frame(Type_of_input, Fertiliser, Pesticide, Herbicide, Sprayer)

library(dplyr)

df_inputs %>%
  select(-Type_of_input) %>%
  summarise_all(sum)

#    Fertiliser Pesticide Herbicide Sprayer
# 1          1         3         2       2
```

You can have a different format like this

```
library(tidyverse)

df_inputs %>%
  select(-Type_of_input) %>%
  summarise_all(sum) %>%
  gather(var, value) %>%
  arrange(desc(value))

#          var value
# 1  Pesticide     3
# 2  Herbicide     2
# 3    Sprayer     2
# 4 Fertiliser     1
```

in case you want to use `value` variable to arrange your dataset and have the most popular values on top.

Comment: how do i summarise, if there is another new column at the end of this data frame e.g. `total_volume <- c(40,50,60)`
I'd like to capture the summary  given a new numeric column

Comment: Can you edit your question and show how you want your output to be?

Comment: My ideal output is a scatter plot. I want to understand the relationship of each of the `Type_of_input` against another column I introduced called `Total_volume`.
In the above example, how do I use the value of `Pesticide` which is 3. to create a scatter plot showing the relationship between pesticide and the values in the numeric column `total_volume`

Answer (score 1):

You simply do:

```
sapply(df_inputs[-1],sum)
```